# What kind of evaluation does the "evaluation" tag refer to?

Tags: discussion, tags

[evaluation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) is currently being used for two different kinds of questions:

1. Questions about assessments, such as evaluating programmers ([such as this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41473/how-can-i-know-whether-i-am-a-good-programmer/))
2. Questions about `eval()` functions ([here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311507/why-are-eval-like-features-considered-evil-in-contrast-to-other-possibly-harmfu))

The tag wiki is currently null or empty.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably take a bit of time and human involvement to fully sort out, but I'd say it's definitely not the first one. Most of those questions should be closed since they are about careers, which is explicitly off-topic here. Once those questions are eliminated from the tag, I'd be curious to see if there are still multiple meanings left and what we can do to either document the tag in terms of a tag wiki or split the tag up and retag into one or more better tags.

Answer (score 1):

From the 21 questions tagged with [evaluation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation), 13 were about "evaluation of expressions in a program" (like a compiler, interpreter or parser). The others are about the evaluation (= rating) of an architecture or an algorithm, or about the assessment of people.

So I think we should give this tag a description which fits to the current majority "evaluation of expressions in a program", and remove the tag from the other questions.

I edited the tag description accordingly, @ThomasOwens, can you please have a look at it and maybe improve it (or delete the description if you don't like it)? If you approve this, I think we can delete the tag from all questions where it does not fit any more.

(Note: in between I edited some of the questions and removed the "evaluation" tag where it does not fit to this more specialized defintion).